# same piece of C++ code works in g++ 4.6 compiler but crashes with 5.1

Tags: c++, g++

The  following  piece of  code  works with g++ 4.6 compiler but crashes  with segmentation fault  when compiled with g++ 5.1 compiler. The variable access gString is  causing  the  segmentation fault.

```
#define _GLIBCXX_DEBUG 1
#define _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI 0

#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

static std::string gString("hello");

static void
__attribute__((constructor))
initialize()
{
    gString.assign("hello world");
    return;
}

static void 
__attribute__((destructor)) 
finalize()
{
    return;
}

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    //std::cerr<<gString;
    return 0;
}
```

GDB output:

```
   Reading symbols from /home/rk/str...done.
(gdb) b initialize
Breakpoint 1 at 0x401419: file str.cc, line 15.
(gdb) r 
Starting program: /home/rk/str 

Breakpoint 1, initialize() () at str.cc:15
15      gString.assign("hello world");
(gdb) n

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004018d6 in std::string::size() const () at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_string.h:3118
3118          { return _M_rep()->_M_length; }
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000000004018d6 in std::string::size() const () at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_string.h:3118
#1  0x00000000004016ff in std::string::assign(char const*, unsigned long) () at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_string.tcc:706
#2  0x000000000040166e in std::string::assign(char const*) () at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_string.h:3542
#3  0x0000000000401428 in initialize() () at str.cc:15
#4  0x00000000004023dd in __libc_csu_init ()
#5  0x00007ffff71ad700 in __libc_start_main () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#6  0x0000000000401289 in _start ()
```

Comment: Adding the flag -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0" makes no difference either.

Comment: Maybe std::cerr is not initialized at that point?

Comment: I see that the std::string implementation changed between gcc-4.* and  gcc-5.* . we are investigating in that direction.

Comment: I have  stopped  printing on to console but still the program crashes, it  seems the storage of the  global string is problem.

Comment: Apparently, your `initialize` function is called before the gString constructor. Have you tried using a global object as @JonathanWakely suggests?

Answer (score 4):

Why are you using `__attribute__((constructor))` in C++ instead of simply a global object with a constructor? Those attributes are useful in C code, but redundant in C++.

The problem is that your constructor runs before the standard iostreams have been initialized, which would not be a problem if you used a global object with a constructor.

You could try adding a priority to your constructor, but I don't think it will help in this case:

```
__attribute__((constructor(999)))
```

Answer (score 3):

The runtime error also happens with gcc 4.9.2 (see [ideone](http://ideone.com/vWH46r) example).

The problem is related to the iostreams which are not yet initialized.  Commenting out the `cerr` line, and everything works fine

Apparently, it's a [known issue](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=39796).

### Edit:  Additional remarks

This small [workaround](http://ideone.com/4Z2NNI) seems to work, at least with 4.9: use c stdio instead of iostreams:

```
fprintf(stderr, "_initialize");  // this works
```

But I fully agree with Jonathan's suggestion of using a global (singleton ?) object relying solely on well defined standard C++ behaviour, unless you really need the constructor being run exactly at the moment of a dynamic library load.

Comment: There is no reason whatsoever to use a Singleton, just make it a global object. Maybe `static` or in an unnamed namespace. [Singleton vs Just Create One](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.SingletonVsJustCreateOne)

Comment: @JonathanWakely Yes, that's true: this is why I put a question mark.  On the other hand, I can imagine that  OP expects his constructor to run only once, and the singleton could address this kind of requirement, if it would be one.

Comment: If you define an object and create one global instance of it then the constructor only runs once. Singleton is an anti-pattern and has no real advantages.

Comment: I have removed  the  cerr,cout from the code and  pasted the new code in the post, still it crashes, it has nothing  to do with the ostream objects being  used uninitialized.